# Brunch is ignoring files starting with an underscore when I build

Tags: brunch

brunch is ignoring a file "_redirects" in my assets folder when I build. What do I add to config to fix? I'm sure there is some way to specifically include this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to overwrite the [default ignored convention](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/lib/utils/config-validate.js#L73) as described in the [Brunch docs](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-conventions-)

```
conventions: {
  ignored: () => false, // override defaults for no ignored files
}
```